# Label problem in figure

Tags: pgfplots

I am new in tikz, in below red boxed parts shows x,y axis labels, Now it's automatically (appearing) incrementing (0,5,10,15,20) my expected out is like (1,2,3,4). I am using the following code. How I change this code?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}
    \begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      xmin=0,xmax=20,
      ymin=0,ymax=20,
      axis y line*=left,
      axis x line*=bottom,
      xlabel={$p_0$ (psi)},
      xlabel near ticks,
      ylabel near ticks
    ]
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean. You've set the limits of both x- and y-axis to be [0,20], so naturally you get numbers up to 20. If you set `xmax` and `ymax` to `4`, then you get numbers up to four. Do you want to keep the axis limits, and just redefine the ticklabels? Or will changing xmax/ymax do what you want? Or do you want to keep the axis limits, but force ticks only at x=[0,1,2,3,4], and similarly for y? (Which would be very weird, I know, so I don't expect you to want that.)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to define where to place tick marks and the label for each mark:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}
    \begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      xmin=0,xmax=20,
      ymin=0,ymax=20,
      axis y line*=left,
      axis x line*=bottom,
      xlabel={$p_0$ (psi)},
      xlabel near ticks,
      ylabel near ticks,
      xtick={0,5,10,15,20},
      xticklabels={0,1,2,3,4},
      ytick={0,5,10,15,20},
      yticklabels={0,1,2,3,4}
    ]
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]